# JMockit Expectation API : How to throw an exception upon method/constructor invocation

Tags: mocking, jmockit, expectations

While using JMockit I want to throw an **exception** upon a **constructor invocation** like this:

```
new Expectations(){
        {
           new FirefoxDriver();//Want to throw IllegalStateException here but how?
        }
};
```

Answer (score 28):

To specify the result for a recorded expectation, assign it (either values to return or exceptions to throw) to the `result` field:

```
new Expectations() {{
    someMockedMethodOrConstructorInvocation(...); result = new IllegalStateException();
}};
```

Comment: I have tried the above; but instead of mocking, it is calling the actual constructor & creating objects instead :(

Comment: You can only record an expectation on a method or constructor which has been *mocked*; usually, that means you declare a mock field or mock parameter using one of the mocking annotations, such as "`@Mocked`". Otherwise, the actual method or constructor is indeed going to be executed.

Comment: @Rogério: adding the mocked field to your example would've been nice. :-) I _think_ it should just be `new Expectations(FirefoxDriver.class) {{...}};` for Affan's case, but am not confident enough with JMockit yet... Maybe add `@Test(expected = IllegalStateException)` to the method, and then call `new FirefoxDriver();` after the expectations block?

Answer (score 0):

we should add the class to be mocked as parameters in the method of the test case.and using result, we can mock the outcome of the method.

```java
@Test
    public void testCase(@Mocked final ClassToMock classToMockObject){  

         new NonStrictExpectations() {
                {       
        classToMockObject.methodToMock();result=NullPointerException(); 
            }};

        classToMockObject.methodToMock(); //calling the method to throw exception
    }
```